# What happens to Marklogic database backup if one cluster node is lost?

Tags: backup, cluster-computing, marklogic

According to ML 9 doco, a database is backed up onto all nodes in the cluster, but the backup process   appears to backup the forests that are only local to each node. So for a database with 6 forests across 3 nodes, I may have 2 forests backup files on each node.

If I have a 3 node cluster and lose one node ( so that one node is now 100% unrecoverable ), are all my backups now effectively useless as they will be missing the back up files for 2 forests?

Or is ML smart enough to re-create the missing data from the dead node, via parity?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to restore a 6 forest backup into just 2 nodes for what should be a 3 node cluster? Generally, you would want to fix that 3rd node first and bring it back online, then restore.

Comment: That kind of answers it, but prompts a question of whether a ML 9 database has sufficient internal resilience and continues to run normally if you lose one node that contains some of the database forests ( assuming no HA forest replication between nodes )? Obviously the data in the lost forests would not be available.

Comment: No, it does not. If you lose pieces of the database it is not complete. You can configure HA replicas so that it can failover and continue with a complete set of data. Otherwise, you need to remove those dead forests from the database, but would obviously then have an incomplete data set.

Comment: My question was based on the scenario directly above, but I have my answer, thanks. Yes if you had replicated forests between nodes you would be OK, like AG replicas in SQL Server. But without replicated forests and should you lose a node ( which means the backups on the dead node are gone ), the database is incomplete. It seems it would function, but the data in the lost forests would not be available. If however you backed up the forests from the now-dead node, you would have been OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is it depends.

Typically backups are made to some sort of network storage, so loosing a node doesn't affect the backups.  If for some reason the backups are stored locally to the system, then it would depend on if you have HA enabled, and whether you are backing up thee replica forests along with the primary forests.

If HA is enabled, you could lose a node and keep running, giving you time to rebuild the lost node.  Alternatively, if you are backing up both the primary and replica forests in your cluster, you would have a complete data set in your backups even if you lose a node.